# How do I assign number of counted ID's from sub-query to plsql declared variable "v_count"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying create a pl/sql block that retrieves manager’s information .

1. List item

The program must prompt the user to enter manager’s number and later displays the total number of employees working under that manager.

```
SERVER OUTPUT ON
DECLARE

 v_last_name s_emp.last_name%TYPE;
 v_first_name s_emp.first_name%TYPE;
 v_count NUMBER (10);
BEGIN


  SELECT DISTINCT last_name,first_name
  INTO v_surname,v_name,v_count
  FROM s_emp 
  WHERE ID IN (SELECT manager_id, COUNT(ID)
               FROM s_emp
               WHERE manager_id = &ID
               GROUP BY manager_id);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Manager '||v_last_name||' 
  '||SUBSTR(v_first_name,1,1)||' ,  has '||v_count||' surbodinates');

END;
```

I've also tried SQL%ROWCOUNT. And i'm not allowed to use loops and Explicit Cursors yet

This is the error i get when i try to run the code:

PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors you made:

- number of columns returned by a `select` statement in PL/SQL must match number of variables you're putting their values into. You can't select 3 values and put them into 2 variables
- `where` clause: `ID` can't be `in` two values returned by a subquery (`manager_id, count(id)`); must be only one
- `sql%rowcount` won't help here, as its value remains 1 (if select returns a row; if it returns more than a single row, that code will raise too-many-rows; if it returns no rows, it'll raise no-data-found)

An example of how you might have done it (based on Scott's sample schema):

```
SQL> set verify off
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    v_ename emp.ename%type;
  3    v_count number;
  4  begin
  5    select ename
  6      into v_ename
  7      from emp
  8      where empno = &&manager_id;
  9
 10    select count(*)
 11      into v_count
 12      from emp
 13      where mgr = &&manager_id;
 14
 15    dbms_output.put_line('Manager ' || v_ename || ' has ' || v_count ||
 16                         ' subordinates');
 17  end;
 18  /
Enter value for manager_id: 7698
Manager BLAKE has 5 subordinates

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```